# How to initiate and unpack vectors in python?

Tags: python, vector

So I am using pygame to learn python and I got the following problem:

I am trying to create a gravity vector `(angle, length)`, like so:

`gravity = pygame.math.Vector2(math.pi, 0.01)`

I've also tried:

`gravity = (math.pi, 0.01)`

But when I try to use the gravity variable in my code I get errors saying that I didn't pass enough parameters, as if it treated the gravity variable as a single value.

When I break it down, for example by doing this:

`... , gravity[0], gravity[1], ...`

It works just fine.

Here's an example function that I want to use with the vector (it takes 4 float values as parameters):

```
(self.angle, self.speed) = add_vectors(self.angle, self.speed, gravity[0], gravity[1])
```

(This one works)

```
(self.angle, self.speed) = add_vectors(self.angle, self.speed, gravity)
```

(this one doesn't work)

What is causing this? Am I initiating the vector wrong or would I have to keep unpacking it by using `gravity[0]` for example?

Comment: Try `add_vectors(self.angle, self.speed, *gravity)` I added a `*`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Could you please tell me a little bit more why it works with a * ?

Comment: `*` is the unpacking operator. You often find it with functions that uses a variable amount of parameters with variable parameter names, see `def my_func(these, variables, are, needed, *argsIsOptional, **kwargsAndSoIsThis)` `*` unpacks an array. `**` unpacks a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gravity variable is a tuple, which is only one object. Your method expects to have 4 arguments but you are passing 3 in the latter example. You could use argument unpacking / destructing.

```
add_vectors(self.angle, self.speed, *gravity)
```

See more about unpacking here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/